# What happens when I type the wrong password?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, cryptography, passwords, encryption

Whenever I type the wrong password on my Ubuntu/Gmail etc it takes some time to ask for password again. But if when I type the right password it immediately logs in.

Why? Is it because the algorithms's best case input is the correct password? Is it illusion then what causes it?

Comment: And it would be great if you try and implement such an algorithm in your webpage.. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common security measure, to prevent unauthorized users from trying a large number of strings to find your password.  By making a short pause after an incorrect entry, it slightly incoveniences the user who enters the wrong password, but it greatly increases the protection from that sort of attack.

Comment: And often the wait period will increase with each incorrect attempt

Comment: Note that, on its own, a simple delay doesn't help if an attacker can set off a boatload of login attempts in parallel. Then he doesn't care how long each one takes, since the artificial delay no longer costs him anything. But you can combine it with a limit on how many simultaneous login attempts you'll process for the same account or from the same source, and either refuse the rest or queue them up so that their delays run in series, not parallel.

Comment: @Steve Actually, it still costs him open connections, which have practical limits. But you're right that ratelimiting globally per account is a much better idea.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's just to prevent someone malicious from trying multiple passwords quickly.

It has nothing to do with the algorithm.